# Enable JDBC in PostgreSQL for non programmer

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I am looking for someone that can explain me in simple terms with written instructions how to create a JDBC in PostgreSQL (I am losing my mind with this). I found other answers in this page and others but I couldn't follow them.

I am no programmer, so I didn't undertand any of the instructions of how to do it in webpages and forums -the method mentioned was configuring the classpath environment variable in the command prompt but I got stuck in the command prompt, I think I have to configure the Java console or something.

I am learning some data mining and I wish to connect to some databases in order to practice. I suppose that for someone knowledgeable in this area this should be an easy job.

I prefer to install a driver in postgresql and not using a bridge.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The phrase “how to create a JDBC” makes no sense.

You need to learn some basics first. Be clear on what [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC) is (a standard for connecting or mediating between a database and a Java app), what a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) is (a particular implementation of JDBC for a specific database.

There are four types of JDBC drivers, the [Type 4 (pure Java)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver#Type_4_driver_.E2.80.93_Database-Protocol_driver_.28Pure_Java_driver.29) being most common in my experience.

For any particular database, you may find there are zero, one or more drivers implemented and available. Some are free-of-cost and open-source, some are not. For example, in Postgres there are two open source drivers, [the classic one](https://jdbc.postgresql.org) and a newer [rewrite-from-scratch one](https://github.com/impossibl/pgjdbc-ng), as well as some commercial products.

A JDBC driver is only useful when trying to connect a Java app to your database. That may be your own app you are writing, or a finished app you obtained such as a database-administration tool.

You must have a [Java implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines) installed on your computer, such as [one from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) or from the [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net) project, or from another vendor such as [Azul](https://www.azul.com) (Zing & Zulu).

You need to learn about the [Java Classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29), the list of all the folders where the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) will be looking for Java classes and [JAR files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)). Read the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html). The easiest way to go is to drop your JDBC driver JAR into an already existing folder on the Classpath, so you do not need to twiddle with setting the Classpath. For example, on a Mac you could drop your driver into `/Library/Java/Extensions`.

The JDBC driver sits *between* the database engine and the Java app. You do not install the JDBC driver *into* the database engine, such as your Questions mentioned, “install a driver in postgresql”.

> [Postgres] ↔ [JDBC driver] ↔ [JVM] ↔ [Java app]